# How to stop folder save location suggestion in ipadOS - Save to Files?

Tags: ios, icloud, ipados, files.app

1. Attempting to save a file to icloud drive via the Save to Files option.
2. On save to files option, I get presented with a small box in the middle of the screen.
3. It takes me to a folder, presumably apple has coded it to *presume* where I might want to file saved.

The problem is:

**This is no where near where I want the file to be saved.**

**The suggested save location is not even in the place where I saved my last file! - (a few minutes before)**

[image]

Is anyone else finding this frustrating issue with “Save to Files?” Can it be changed? I don’t even mind it starting at the base level, the file locations. I’m just annoyed at having to come out of a weird suggested save location, every time.

Alternatively, Is there any alternatives or better ways of file management on iPadOS?

Comment: Strange - nearly every time I save it gives me the last location I saved into.  The **only** time it does not is when I have rebooted / powered on the iPad.  My tablet is the old 9.7 iPad Pro with the latest OS.

Comment: @Andyroo the suggested save location does change for me, but slowly, after a few days.  I just can’t comprehend apple’s mentality of ‘you saved something here previously, therefore you are going to want to save the next thing to the exact same place’